# Matrix Identity in haskell without list

Tags: haskell

I want to make an Identity matrix without list syntax or list functions  for eg something with tuple `(x,x)` ...and i want to print it like

```
*> showMatrix (matrixIdentity 4)
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Comment: What type should `matrixIdentity` have? At the moment, `matrixIdentity :: Int -> Int`, and `showMatrix :: Int -> String` would solve this. But that's not what you actually want.

Comment: showMatrix :: Int -> String , matrixIdentity :: Int -> Int, it was correct

Comment: @abdessamadabba `matrixIdentity` taking an `Int` makes sense, but if it returns an `Int`, then where exactly is your matrix in this code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to create an identity matrix

```
import Data.List.Split(splitEvery)
identity n = splitEvery n $ take (n*n) $ concat $ replicate n (1:replicate n 0)
```

Now, to get the output in that format you can

```
putStr $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show) (identity 3)
```

to package these all

```
import Data.List.Split(splitEvery)
data IdentityMatrix = I Int
showMatrix :: IdentityMatrix -> IO ()
showMatrix (I n) = putStr $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show) identity
       where identity = splitEvery n $ take (n*n) $ concat $ replicate n (1:replicate n 0)


> showMatrix (I 4)
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Comment: *"I want to make a Identify matrix without syntax list or __list functions__"*. However, the question isn't clear at the moment. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Zeta What I thought was asked whether one can print the matrix form of an identity matrix without actually creating the matrix in concrete beforehand.  What I think I answered is you can have it created when it's printed out.